# Change redirect_uri when logout from Keycloak account page

Tags: keycloak

We are trying to redirect users to http://destionation.com/home when they logout from **Keycloak Account Management** page http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MY_REALM/account/ (screenshot):

[image: Keycloak Account Management]

However, it always redirects to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/KLARA/account/ after signing out. Is there any official way to change that `redirect_uri`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logoutUrl is built from the base server url (here: http://localhost:8080/auth) :

```java
config.setLogoutEndpoint(frontendUriBuilder.clone().path(OIDCLoginProtocolService.class, "logout").build(realm.getName(), OIDCLoginProtocol.LOGIN_PROTOCOL).toString());
```

You can't configure a specific url for the logout endpoint in Account Management.

But you can easily create a custom theme and override the logoutUrl value : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. We had a link from the Angular app to the Keycloak account page. After changing the password, user could click logout but the redirect_uri was pointing to the same account page. Hence after logging in, user was again redirected to account page and stuck in a loop. My solution was as follows.

Send the redirect URI from Angular or any app:

```
{URL to account page of Keycloak} + '?redirectUri=' + {path to the Home page my app}
```

Then in Keycloak themes account/password.ftl added the following javascript on top:

```
<script>
var redirectUri;
window.onload = function() {
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
redirectUri = urlParams.get('redirectUri')
document.getElementById( "backButton" ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript:goBack();" );
};

var goBack = function() {
window.location.replace(redirectUri);
}
</script>
```

Finally added a doBack label in message.properties and a Back button next to Save:

```
<button id="backButton" type="button" class="${properties.kcButtonClass!}${properties.kcButtonDefaultClass!}${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}" name="submitAction" value="Cancel">${msg("doBack")}</button>
```